# Добавить кастомный заголовок в http request

Tags: php

Нужно добавить кастомный заголовок в http header request. Не могу понять как

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

Comment: Эта функция отправляет в response а мне нужно в request

Comment: а чем вы делаете request?

Comment: Пытался таким способом `$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
      'method'=>"GET",
      'header'=>"key: test\r\n"
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents('http://injector/', false, $context);`

Comment: И таким
`$url = "http://injector/";          
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Key: test']); 
$head = curl_exec($ch); 
if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}<br>";
}
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch); 
var_dump($head);`
Буду рад любой информации

Comment: @Sedoy Вы правильно делаете (по крайней мере в варианте с `file_get_contents`). Почему вы решили, что это не работает? Как проверяете?

Comment: Тут моя ошибка была я обращался к ссылке текущей страницы. (вообще так можно? и скорее всего до ее полного формирования) Сам запрос отрабатывает, но в request header  я не вижу своего кастомного поля. Оно там должно отображаться?